# Which AWS services am I using?

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I sign into the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/), I just see a list of all the services. How do I know which ones I'm using? Can I hide the ones I'm not using?

I much prefer the way Heroku organizes things. It shows your apps first. Then, when you click into an app, it only shows the add-ons (services) that app is using. Imagine logging into Heroku and just seeing a list of all [Heroku add-ons](https://addons.heroku.com).

Comment: I also reported this issue on [AWS' Developer Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=179903&tstart=0).

Comment: Why is it so complicated to figure out what I'm paying for?!? Oh wait...

Answer (score 25):

### UPDATE: 2019-02-22 09:39:25

> - A user on the stackexchange network reports that this answer is no longer valid, due to a change made by AWS

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- Use the `tag editor` feature of `AWS Resource Groups` to report AWS services usage.

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- Amazon Web Services console (AWSConsole)
- Current version as of 2017-06-11
- Tracking any of various AWS Resources

#### Problem

- **Scenario:** AWSUserDipasq wants a report showing all used resources for a specific AWSConsole
- AWSUserDipasq does not have a handy record or report at hand

  - Example: AWSUserDipasq inherited an AWS configuration from someone else
  - Example: AWSUserDipasq setup the configuration a long time ago, and forgot what he did
  - Example: AWSUserDipasq used some third-party service to configure one or more resources on the specific AWSConsole
- AWSUserDipasq notices that the AWSBillingReport does not show enough detail

  - Example: AWSBillingReport only shows those items with no associated usage fee
  - Example: AWSBillingReport only shows those items which have already incurred costs in the previous billing period

#### Solution

Use the `tag editor` feature of `AWS Resource Groups`.

Step-by-Step:

- STEP: Login to the relevant AWSConsole
- STEP: Choose `Resource Groups` from the main AWSConsole
- STEP: Choose `tag editor` from the Resource Groups submenu
- STEP: Under `Find resources to tag :: Regions` choose all the AWS regions available
- STEP: Under `Find resources to tag :: Resource Types` choose `All resource types`
- STEP: Choose `Find Resources`

When these steps are successfully completed, the result will be a report of all the AWS Resources that are deployed on the relevant AWSConsole

#### Pitfalls

- This approach may show resources that are allocated for deployment, but still not actually used.

#### See also

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/creating-a-resource-group.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html

Comment: Using this method still returns hundreds of results - any tips on the big ones to look for from there?

Comment: @ognockocaten Unfortunately the best approach is probably going to require some manual bookkeeping, such as using a resource group (see answer by @ma11hew28) or tagging.

Answer (score 2):

Once you figure out what services you're using, you may want to create a [resource group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/resource-groups.html) to group them together.

Answer (score 0):

AWS introduced AWS Config for audit purpose. AWS Config is a service that enables you to assess, audit, and evaluate the configurations of your AWS resources. Config continuously monitors and records your AWS resource configurations and allows you to automate the evaluation of recorded configurations against desired configurations.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/config/

Answer (score 0):

Login to your AWS account using Resource Auditor Role and check the billing. Under Billing Details you can see what you are running under which region.

Do pin the Billing server to see the same once you login.